De-duplicate data from Autoloader in Databricks
I want to read in files using the Databricks Autoloader. I want to drop_duplicates and take the newer value, since it is possible that values can appear in newer files and even be updated.
In non-SparkStreaming contexts, I have always used:
df.withColumn('rank', F.rank().over(Window.partitionBy("ID")
                                          .orderBy(F.desc('timestamp'))))
  .where(F.col('rank') == 1)
  .drop('rank')

But this fails with the Autoloader.
I have tried
df = df 
  .withWatermark("timestamp", "7 days") \
  .dropDuplicates(["ID", "timestamp"])

this runs, but is not taking care of the duplicates, which are typically 3-4 days apart at max.
Any ideas how I can achieve this with the Autoloader?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69358223/handling-duplicates-in-databricks-autoloader

can you check the above and let me know if it helped you??

This question is similar to: Handling Duplicates in Databricks autoloader. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As you mentioned that you want to implement deduplication data from Autoloader in Databricks
You need to use Delta tables merge capability to insert only the new data into the Delta table.
This should be done within the foreachBatch function.
Note that you need to create Delta table when you writestream.
For example I have sample dataset in my source_data_loc like below:
Id  Name    Age
1   Michale 25
2   Tom 35
3   Sonny   36
4   Fredo   26
5   Vito    90
5   Vito    90

I have tried the below approach:
def merge_batch(microBatchOutputDF, batchId):
    print(f"Processing batch {batchId}")
    
    
    microBatchOutputDF.printSchema()
    microBatchOutputDF.show(5)
    
    
    if not DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, target_data_loc):
        print("Delta table does not exist. Creating new table...")
        microBatchOutputDF.write.format("delta").save(target_data_loc)
    else:
        deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, target_data_loc)
        (deltaTable.alias("t")
         .merge(microBatchOutputDF.alias("s"), "t.Id = s.Id")
         .whenMatchedUpdateAll()
         .whenNotMatchedInsertAll()
         .execute())
query = (df.writeStream
         .format("delta")
         .outputMode("append")
         .foreachBatch(merge_batch)
         .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_loc)
         .start(target_data_loc))
query.awaitTermination()

In the above code handling each micro-batch of streaming data.
Merging the micro-batch DataFrame with the existing Delta table. The merge operation uses the condition t.Id = s.Id to match records
When Matched Updates all columns of existing records with the data from the micro-batch DataFrame.
When Not Matched Inserts new records into the Delta table if they do not already exist.
Results:
+---+-------+---+-------------+
|Id |Name   |Age|_rescued_data|
+---+-------+---+-------------+
|1  |Michale|25 |NULL         |
|2  |Tom    |35 |NULL         |
|3  |Sonny  |36 |NULL         |
|4  |Fredo  |26 |NULL         |
|5  |Vito   |90 |NULL         |
+---+-------+---+-------------+

